# How to prevent LTeX from spamming my "PROBLEMS" tab

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, tex

I am using the vscode extension LTeX to help me find misspell in my LaTeX documents.
But there is one thing that annoys me, it also finds "misspells" in some latex configuration files. How can I prevent LTeX from spamming the "PROBLEMS" tab in vscode like pic related ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wkO5.png)

I tried to look the extension settings tab of LTeX. I was expecting to find a settings to prevent it from outputting in the "PROBLEMS" tab

Comment: create an issue at the extension repo to add a filter, include and exclude, for the reported problems

Comment: if you do so, please also add a link here to that issue for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

The solution :

https://github.com/valentjn/vscode-ltex/discussions/838#discussioncomment-5825524

Need to set "ltex.diagnosticSeverity": "hint" in settings.json